# Linear Algebra 4th edition by Friedberg exercise 12 in section 2.7

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $V$ be the solution space of an $n$th-order homogeneous linear differential equation with constant coefficients having auxiliary polynomial $p(t)$. Prove that if $p(t) = g(t)h(t)$, where $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ are polynomials of postive degree, then 
>   $$N(h(D)) = R(g(D_V)) = g(D)(V),$$
>   where $D_V : V \to V$ is defined by $D_V(x) = x'$ for $x\in V$. Hint: first prove $g(D)(V) \subseteq N(h(D))$. Then, prove that the two spaces have the same finite dimension.

Let $x \in g(D)(V)$. Then, there exists $y \in V$, such that $g(D)(y) =x$. Note that $p(D)(y) = 0$ since $y \in V$. This implies that 
$$p(D)(y) = g(D)h(D)(y) = h(D)g(D)(y) = h(D)(x) = 0.$$
Therefore, $x\in N(h(D))$. I am struggling with the second part of the hint. First, note that by dimension theorem, $\dim(V) = \dim(N(g(D_V)) + \dim(R(g(D_V))$, and that $N(g(D_V)) = N(g(D))$ since $N(g(D)) \subseteq V$, and that I have a theorem that the solution space $N(g(D))$ has a dimension equal to the degree of $g$. Taken all together, $\dim(N(g(D_V)) = g$ (let $g$ be the degree of $g$), and this implies that $\dim(R(g(D_V)) = n-g$. Therefore, if I show that $\dim(N(h(D)) = n-g$, it finishes the proof. I have a theorem that if $p(D) = g(D)h(D)$ and $g(D)$ (or $h(D)$) is onto, then 
$$\dim(N(p(D)) = \dim(N(g(D)) + \dim(N(h(D)).$$
I know that $\dim(N(p(D)) = n$ and $\dim(N(g(D)) = g$. But, I do not know that $g(D)$ (or $h(D)$) is onto.

How can I show that either one operator is onto or is there another way to reach the answer?

Comment: also see: https://math.solverer.com/library/stephen_friedberg/linear_algebra/exercise_2-7-12?utm_source=stackexchange.com&utm_medium=link

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the last result, you only need recall that, for any two polynomials $p(t)$ and $q(t)$ over a field (or an integral domain) we have that
$$\deg \big( p(t)q(t) \big) = \deg p(t) + \deg q(t)$$
Now, in your case
$$n=\dim \textsf{N}(p(\textsf D)) = \dim \textsf{N}(g(\textsf D)) + \dim \textsf{N}(h(\textsf D)) = \textsf{g} + \dim \textsf{N}(h(\textsf D))$$
and it follows that
$$\dim \textsf{N}(h(\textsf D)) = n- \textsf g =\dim \textsf{R}(g(\textsf D _\textsf V))$$ and this 
$$\textsf{N}(h(\textsf D))=\textsf{R}(g(\textsf D _\textsf V))$$
The theorem you mention is for linear operators in general, but in this case it is valid since we are talking about the degree of a polynomial.